# merge is making duplicates if 2 queries run concurrently

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MERGE (n:Label {
  value: $value
})
ON CREATE SET
  n.another_value = $another_value,
  n.created = timestamp()
RETURN id(n);
```

If I run this query concurrently, I receive 2 equal nodes.
I need only one. What I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in neo4j that was fixed a while back. To quote from the last section of [this knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/):

> **Note for Neo4j < 3.0.9 for 3.0.x versions, and < 3.1.2 for 3.1.x versions**
>
> A bug in the cost planner for affected versions prevented
>   double-checked locking on MERGE. This allowed race conditions which
>   could result in duplicate patterns being created by concurrent MERGE
>   operations, or other write operation which caused the previously
>   non-existent pattern to exist.
>
> We recommend upgrading to a version which includes this bug fix.